# How to append XML nodes using existing Nant or Nant Contrib tasks?

Tags: xml, nant

During a build process using Nant, how to update an xml file, for adding new nodes. I wish to do this by using existing Nant/NantContrib tasks

Answer (score 5):

here's an article explaining in some detail: http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2008/01/03/appending-nodes-in-xml-files-with-xmlpeek-and-xmlpoke-using-nant.aspx

Basically...

1. use `xmlpeek` to load the nodes you want to append to into a variable
2. append your new node (as a string) to the variable from step 1
3. use `xmlpoke` to replace the nodes selected in step 1

   <xmlpeek file="${configFile}" xpath="/configuration/appSettings" property="appSettingsNodes" />

   <property name="newAppSettingsNodes" value="${appSettingsNodes}<add key='my.config.key' value='${someNewValue}' /&gt;" />

   <xmlpoke file="${configFile}" xpath="/configuration/appSettings" value="${newAppSettingsNodes}" />

Comment: Works great but there is an ilegal character in the "newAppSettingsNodes" value, replace `<` with `&lt;` and is all good. It shoud look like this: `<property name="newAppSettingsNodes" value="${appSettingsNodes}&lt;add key='my.config.key' value='${someNewValue}' /&gt;" />`

Answer (score 2):

You might use [`<xmlpoke>`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/nightly/latest/help/tasks/xmlpoke.html) for that.

But I would suggest, you do yourself a favor and use [`<script>`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/nightly/latest/help/tasks/script.html) to write xml file modification logic in the language of your choice.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to _add_ nodes with `xmlpoke`. That's only for modifying existent nodes.

Comment: @ Diego Jancic: I agree. What you could do is modifying the parent node. First you `<xmlpeek>` the parent, attach the desired new child node to its content and `<xmlpoke>` it then